# Please recommend a tool of terminal cast

Tags: software-recommendation, screencast

I'd like to show some of my live actions in terminal, and their output to some people around the globe. I could use tools like VNC for this. But since terminal data is way simpler than GUI, I wonder if there is a tool better suited for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found [tmate](http://tmate.io). And since one could host his own tmate server, I think this is the tool I was seeking.

Comment: Didn't know tmate allowed read-only access :) so cool.

Answer (score 1):

These things can help you

1. [Termcast](http://noway.ratry.ru/jsn/termcast/)
2. You can use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Multiuser-Session.html) command with these arguments to have multisession but to be honest i dont know how many sessions are possible.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>While I don't think you can do this live, you *can* use the [Shelr tool](https://github.com/shelr/shelr.tv).</strike>

Shelr is supposed to allow you to take a "screencast" of your terminal and then save it to shelr.tv - where people can access it later. However, http://www.shelr.tv has apparently disappeared - so that may be out of the question.

**Edit**:
Yup. I can officially confirm that Shelr is, in fact, dead. The official twitter announced this in August of 2014.

However, the code is still available [here](https://github.com/shelr/shelr.tv) - so you may be able to take a look at that and possibly create your own tool!